# Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a doubt in serialization.

example:

```
interface IBase {}

[DataContract]
class Base : IBase
{
  [DataContract]
  public Derived Child{get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Base))]
class Derived : Base
{
  [DataMember]
  public IBase Parrent {get;set;}
}
```

If I try to store an instance of `Base` class in `IsolatedStorage`, it is not getting executed; it hangs. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your attributes are *all over the place* - `Base.Child` is a `[DataMember]`, not a `[DataContract]`. IIRC in phone 7 you need public types for serialization; and it is the *base* that needs informing of *children*. However; the `IBase` is another problem; that isn't designated as a contract. If possible, change that to `Base` (not `IBase`), as the serializer needs to know about all concrete contracts.

So:

```
public interface IBase {}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base : IBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public Derived Child{get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Derived : Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public Base Parent {get;set;}
}
```

Additionally, a `Parent` member is a big problem for tree serializers (and `DataContractSerializer` *is* a tree serializer, unless you explicitly enable full-graph mode).

You *might* be able to get DCS to like `IBase`, but you'd need to investigate marking that as a contract and noting the concrete types. If you can't get anywhere with that, I know protobuf-net supports that layout (although I haven't  tested that *specifically* for phone 7, but there is no fundamental reason it can't work).

Comment: Just to confirm, yes, you can only serialize public types on Windows Phone.